# Is there a way to add a post in wordpress via googlescript?

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, post, wordpress-rest-api, urlfetch

I have a form in googlescript where I can add a user to a sheet.
Is there a way to implement some lines in that code so the script adds a post on a wordpress page?
I read that it's possible via wp_insert_post , but I have no idea how that works in my case.

EDIT: 
As Spencer suggested I tried to do it via WP REST API.

The following code seems to be working .............

```
function httpPostTemplate() {
  // URL for target web API
  var url = 'http://example.de/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';


  // For POST method, API parameters will be sent in the
  // HTTP message payload.
  // Start with an object containing name / value tuples.
  var apiParams = {
    // Relevant parameters would go here
    'param1' : 'value1',
    'param2' : 'value2'   // etc.
  };

  // All 'application/json' content goes as a JSON string.
  var payload = JSON.stringify(apiParams);

  // Construct `fetch` params object
  var params = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': payload,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true

  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)

  // Check return code embedded in response.
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  if (rc !== 200) {
    // Log HTTP Error
    Logger.log("Response (%s) %s",
               rc,
               responseText );
    // Could throw an exception yourself, if appropriate
  }
  else {
    // Successful POST, handle response normally
    Logger.log( responseText );
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

> [16-09-28 21:24:29:475 CEST] Response (401.0)
>   {"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to
>   create new posts.","data":{"status":401}}

Means: I have to authenticate first.
I installed the plugin: WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server
I setup a new user and got a client key and client user.
But from here I have no clue what to do : /

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the basic auth, like this:

```
  // Construct `fetch` params object
  var params = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': payload,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    "headers" : {
       "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)+"",
       "cache-control": "no-cache"
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Wordpress has a REST API. I can be found at:

> http://v2.wp-api.org/

You will use the UrlFetchApp Service to access this api. Documentation can be found at:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Read the docs and try to write some code. It you get stuck post the code that is confusing you here and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to authentificate :/
I'll update my current code..

Answer (score 1):

You should add you authentification in the header :

```
var headers = {
  ... ,
  'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode('USERNAME:PASSWORD'),
};
```

And then add your header in your parameters :

```
var params = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': headers,
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
}
```

And then use UrlfetchApp.fetch

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts/", params)
Logger.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for giving me these important links.
<3

I installed WP REST API and the OAuth plugin. 
In the documentation is written:

> Once you have WP API and the OAuth server plugins activated on your
>   server, you’ll need to create a “client”. This is an identifier for
>   the application, and includes a “key” and “secret”, both needed to
>   link to your site.

I couldn't find out how to setup a client?

In my GoogleScriptCode according to the WP API I get the error:

```
{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create new posts.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Edit: I found it - it's under User/Application
I'll try to figure it out and get back to you later.